# iOS Key Events Without Text Field

Tags: ios

Is it possible to receive key events in iOS from an external Bluetooth keyboard without needing a text filed or text area with focus?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to implement `UIKeyInput` protocol.  This is how my iCADE SDK works.  Check out the iCadeReaderView class [here on github](https://github.com/scarnie/iCade-iOS/tree/master/iCadeTest/iCade).